# What does `#[0` (hash angle bracket 0) mean in the elisp debugger?

Tags: debugging, byte-compilation, edebug

When using the [debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugger.html#Debugger)
I get lines like the following in the stack trace:

```
#[0 "\302\303!\210\300\211\207" [describe-input-method this-command helm-mode 1] 2 "\n\n(fn)"]()
```

I have no clue what the `#[0` notation means in this context? It seems like it is called like a function?

<sub>I tried googling, but good luck with finding "#[0" on google. Some of my best attempts was "pound-open-angle-bracket-0" or hash-angle-bracket-0, but they didn't yield anything (which this question will hopefully change).</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at compiled byte code.

From [`(elisp) Byte-Code Type`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Byte_002dCode-Type.html):

> The printed representation and read syntax for a byte-code function
>   object is like that for a vector, with an additional ‘#’ before the
>   opening ‘[’.

Comment: So what does the different parts of the vector mean? I'm guessing that "\302..." is the bytecode.

Comment: Yes, these are opcodes. Just use `M-x disassemble` to see it's disassembly.

Comment: See also https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Byte_002dCode-Objects.html#Byte_002dCode-Objects for more info on how byte code objects work (and what the parts of the vector are).